# iOS app suddenly can't find file

Tags: ios

Original post:

> I've got an iOS app which happily loads files successfully a few times and then all of a >sudden, with no apparent reason, fails to load the files again. The paths all seem correct >seeing as they load successfully to start with... does any one know of any reason this could >happen?
>
> I first noticed this running the app on an ipod touch but it also happens in the iphone >simulator as well. I'm using XCode 4.2 and iOS6.

Edit:
It turns out that the audio system I was using wasn't releasing the audio player objects properly so presumably they ended up keeping file handles open or something, resulting in new files failing to open. Adding in a release to the audio players when they finished seems to have solved the problem or at least significantly reduced the likelihood of it happening!

If you run into similar problems where files won't open you can check to make sure file handles aren't being left open (each fopen should have a fclose with it when the file is no longer needed).

Comment: Code please? Have you done anything to try to narrow down where the problem might lie?

Comment: Load the files from where?  What kind of files?

Comment: Upon further investigation it looks like it might be poor management of audioplayer objects that's causing it... possibly they're not releasing their file handles or something and causing issues trying to open other files...